# Create and Delete Resource Group in Azure using Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

Scenario :

I create a main.bicep file containing one resource group :

I scope the command to the subscription and create the resource group.

```
New-AzSubscriptionDeployment -TemplateFile .\main.bicep
```

I now want to delete the same resource group using the .bicep file , in Terraform i could do this by removing or commenting out the RG , but in Bicep it seems like the -Mode command needs to be scoped to resources in an existing RG and i cannot use the `New-AzSubscriptionDeployment -Mode Complete` command to remove the RG resource from Azure.

Is this a limitation of Bicep ? Does Resource Groups need to be manually removed when no longer needed ?

Comment: You could use the `Remove-AzResourceGroup` command to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, yes they need to be removed manually.  This isn't so much a limitation of bicep as it is the Azure platform.

There is a capability on the horizon that will allow you to clean up empty resourceGroups, no public ETA for that but it is in private preview at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your response ! Hopefully Microsoft adds the feature like in Terraform where resource groups that are removed or commented out from the file is removed when running the command in "complete" mode.